# Dynamic SQL and loop challenge, SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have n tables that is unknown before runtime with tablename always being tablename1, tablename2... tablenameN. The first column of each table is always Name. The challenge is to change that column name in each table to Name1, Name2.. NameN. I know I should be using sp_rename and a loop. Having trouble building up the query, I'm pretty new to SQL. Help would be appreciated. THanks

Comment: Did you find any of the answers useful?

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong with your attempt when you don't post any code.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the rename:

```
DECLARE @counter INT;
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @newColumnName NVARCHAR(100);

SET @counter = 1;
WHILE @counter < 65536
BEGIN
    SET @tableName = 'tableName' + CAST(@counter AS NVARCHAR)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @tableName)
    BEGIN
        SET @columnName = @tableName + N'.name';
        SET @newColumnName = N'name' + CAST(@counter AS NVARCHAR);
        EXEC sp_rename @objname=@columnName, @newName=@newColumnName;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @counter = 65536
    END

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

It's a bit crude though.. and renames only 65535 tables and full amount only when there's none missing in between.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment sql_exec when you're sure it does what you're expecting :)

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname, @ColName sysname
DECLARE @num sysname
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE cTables CURSOR FOR SELECT name from dbo.sysobjects where Category = 0 AND type NOT IN (N'F', N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'P', N'TR', N'V', N'K') AND name like 'tablename%'
OPEN cTables
FETCH NEXT FROM cTables INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @num = SUBSTRING(@Tablename, 10, 5)
    SET @sql = N'sp_RENAME ''' + @TableName + '.[Name]'' , ''[Name' + @num + ']'', ''COLUMN'''
    PRINT @sql
--  EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql
    FETCH NEXT FROM cTables INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE cTables;
DEALLOCATE cTables;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SP - give it a try ;-)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Rename
(
    @n INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @i INT
    DECLARE @tabname NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @colname NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @i = 1

    WHILE @i <= @n
    BEGIN
        SET @tabname = N'tablename' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
        SET @colname = N'name' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(MAX))  

        IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.tables t WHERE t.name = @tabname)
        BEGIN
            SET @Stmt = N'EXEC sp_rename ''' + @tabname + '.[name]'', ''' + @colname +''',''COLUMN'''
            --PRINT @Stmt
            EXEC sp_executesql @Stmt
        END

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
END
```